# Astronomy A Physical Perspective

Tags: astrophysics, cosmology

Is "Astronomy: A Physical Perspective" by M. Kutner written in 2003 a good introductory textbook? What other textbooks could you recommend? I want to study astronomy on my own but with scientific rigor (not just from popular science)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Book recommendation](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32350/book-recommendation)